Flutter widget build causes a list of widget to appear in different sequence even with UniqueKey()
For some reason the widgets are not behaving as expected when the floating action button is clicked:
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> widgets = [
    Container(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      child: Text("0", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
    ),
    Container(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      child: Text("1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
    ),
    Container(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
      child: Text("2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
    ),
  ];

  List<int> homePageWidgetSequence = [0, 1, 2];

  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          if (homePageWidgetSequence[i] == 0) widgets[i],
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          if (homePageWidgetSequence[i] == 1) widgets[i],
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          if (homePageWidgetSequence[i] == 2) widgets[i],
        Text((count-1).toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40))
      ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          if (count == 0) {
            homePageWidgetSequence = [1, 0, 2];
          } else if (count == 1) {
            homePageWidgetSequence = [2, 0, 1];
          } else if (count == 2) {
            homePageWidgetSequence = [2, 1, 0];
          }
          print(count);
          count++;
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}

The widgets are suppose to be displaying sequence 2,0,1 but it displays 1,2,0 instead. It worked when count equals 0 and 2.
Screenshot
I was suspecting some sort of key issue when building but it doesn't fix it after adding UniqueKey(), could someone help me with it? Thank you!

Tried but still have the same error

I would simply build the needed widget without any caching in widgets list

Thx for the advice. This issue actually originated from this issue I posted like an hour ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78841664/flutter-list-of-widget-sequence-changing-using-draggable-and-dragtarget-causes-d
I was able to boil that one down to the current one.

have you seen 10 minutes vid https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc?si=_uc9d3OoZdwCnmtD from the flutter devs?

Yeah I was just checking on that, I think I was on to something let me do some more experiments

@YuCao
did you have to use for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)           if (homePageWidgetSequence[i] == 0) widgets[i], in Column?  If not I think I got solution for you

That's not necessary
